# Selecting an element ID that was created in an innerHTML variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage, innerhtml, template-literals, queryselector

How do I select the textfield element "member-name"?

```
function revealPaywall (){
  const paywall = document.getElementById('paywall')
  const name = localStorage.getItem("value");
//TO WRITE MULTILINE HTML IN JS, USE BACKTICKS `` TO CREATE A TEMPLATE LITERAL
  if (localStorage.getItem("value") === null){
    paywall.innerHTML =
      `
      <h1>This Is An Example Of A Paywall<h1>
      <p>If you enter a name, it will be saved to the localStorage. To bypass just enter your name and click the "submit" button<p>
        <label for="name">Member Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="member-name">
        <br><br><br>
        <button onclick="paywallComplete()">SUBMIT</button>
      `
  }
}
function paywallComplete (){
  const paywallName = document.querySelector("#member-name");
  if (paywallName.value === null){
    window.alert('hi');
  }
```

Am I selecting it correctly? if so why am I not getting a 'hi' alert when clicking on the submit button. I press it with the textfield empty so I'm assuming the `paywallName.value === null` should be true. I tried `querySelector(`#member-name`)` & `querySelector(`member-name`)` to no avail.

Comment: `paywallName.value === null should be true` No.  Empty string is not exactly equal to null.

Comment: Try printing `paywallName.value` to see what it actually is to debug your `if` statement: `console.log(typeof paywallName.value, paywallName.value)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript, when an input field is empty, its value is not null, but an empty string (""). So, when you check paywallName.value === null, it won't be true for an empty input field.

```
function paywallComplete() {
  const paywallName = document.querySelector("#member-name");
  if (paywallName.value === "") {
    window.alert('hi');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you add elements with DOM object?
For example, in order to add the `input` element, add this code:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "text";
input.id = "member-name";
paywall.appendChild(input);
```

Also you can summarize these codes by jquery.